# Generate negative reference voltage

Tags: voltage-reference, negative

In my current design, I need to include force measurement. [A301 sensor](https://www.tekscan.com/products-solutions/force-sensors/a301?tab=description) is selected for this. Now, in order to be able to have analog voltage proportional to the force applied, I need to have negative reference voltage VREF in a range from -1.25V to -0.25V (fixed or adjustable).

I know there are a few approaches for generating negative output voltage (inverting with Opamps, using CMOS charge-pump inverters etc). However, I was unable to select devices for a range -1.25V to -0.25V.

Would you like to give me some hints on how to generate a negative reference voltage in above range (fixed or adjustable. E.g. -0.9V)?

Thanks in advance for your time and effort, really appreciate it!
Sincerely,
Bojan.

Comment: You may not need any separate negative voltage. You can generate the necessary offset by positively offsetting the (+) input to your amplifier. Same effect.

Comment: well, it is desired to have reference voltage with opposite polarity to supply voltage. This way, output voltage VOUT will be positive and appropriate for A/D conversion.

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided went to some useless product splash page, not a datasheet.  This answer will only be general since the details of the device are unknown.

The first thing you need to find out is how much current the device needs at this negative voltage.  If it is small enough, a charge pump can do this.  You don't even need a charge pump chip.  If you already have a suitably fast clock signal, or can easily arrange for one, then all you need is two diodes and two capacitors.  Many microcontrollers can be configured to output some internal clock, for example.

Starting with 3.3 V and using two silcon diodes will result in about -1.9 V.  You could use a resistor and another diode as a shunt regulator to make about -700 mV.  There are various options.

Another point to look at is whether you really need a negative supply.  The device itself only sees the voltage difference across its power terminals.  It doesn't know whether you consider either of them negative or positive.  If the device puts out a analog signal, then maybe you can deal with the offset of the signal instead of offsetting the power voltage of the device.

Comment: The splash page looks goofy indeed. I think this is a kind of conductive foam sensor, a variable resistor, with about 5 MOhm impedance at no load. They need to offset this and make the output 0-to-5V, for convenience. Lack of technical data looks suspicious.

Comment: It is indeed a variable resistor. Would it better to use non-inverting configuration of Opamp with the gain of (1+R2/R1)?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is the recommended circuit from A301 datasheet. The link I provided contains the link to A301 datasheet in pdf.